# how can I give hover effect to overlapped nodes (z-index)

Tags: javascript, hover, overlap

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col"/>
  <div class="col"/>
  <div class="col"/>
  <div class="col"/>
  <div class="col"/>
  <div class="row"/>
  <div class="row"/>
  <div class="row"/>
  <div class="row"/>
  <div class="row"/>
</div>
```

and this col & row are overlapped like this

[image]

I want to give hover effect to both elements.
I tried with jQuery event handler
but the behind one is a
dynamically generated node 
so I tried something like this

```
$('html').on('mouseover', '-behindOne-', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

but `event.target` was higher overlapped node
and `event.current` was html
and `this` was `undefined`
what should I do?

---

I want to effect `background-color` change.
I want use hover `event at same time`.
each hover event works well
but at the center of that Pic
only effect on higher one  (z-index)

also i can't do like this

```css
.wrap:hover .col {}
.wrap:hover .row {}
```

it should only effect on mouseOvered col and row

## I want this!~~

[image]

Comment: Please describe what kind of hover effect you want

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hover effect on both of them

```
.col:hover{
  //change somethings
}

.row:hover{
  //change somethings
}
```

but this code may help just for css tricks.
you can try also with jquery like

```
$( ".col" ).mouseover(function() {
  //change somethings
});
$( ".row" ).mouseover(function() {
  //change somethings
});
```

and please explain what do you want to change exactly with hover effect

PLUS div-->

```
  //this is html block
 <div class=plus>
  <div class="col"/>
  <div class="row"/>
 </div>

   //this is css block
  .plus div:hover{
    background-color:black
  }
```

Comment: but that one effect on only higher one i wan't effect on both in same time

Comment: ok if you want to change the background of whole plus figure you may try  -->     <div class=plus><div class="col"/>
<div class="row"/><div>    then you can change plus class like      .plus div:hover{}     its clear in my answer. i updated it

Comment: sorry ... there is another col and row is exist.... each one must have hover effect...

Comment: so you want to change background color for both elements when its mouseover on intersect area and change the color on mouseover for each elements separataly

Comment: Berfin Tanrıverd //  yes!